# What exactly UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject does

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I found UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject very strange when reading the JDK ConcurrentLinkedQueue. (class CLQ is copy from ConcurrentLinkedQueue for easy debug...)

When I offer the first item to ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

- before

  `p.casNext(null, newNode)`

  head==tail==p==t ref the same object, like this.

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dCO0.png
- step into casNext after

  `UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, nextOffset, cmp, val);`

  p.next is ref to the newNode as expected, like this.

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNtUN.png
- step out to offer

  Everything become strange... I can understand why p.next ref wound change to p, how head ref newNode automatically...

  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pvvcy.png

code: ConcurrentLinkedQueue.class offer()

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
    checkNotNull(e);
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e);

    for (Node<E> t = tail, p = t;;) {
        Node<E> q = p.next;
        if (q == null) {
            // p is last node
            if (p.casNext(null, newNode)) {
                // Successful CAS is the linearization point
                // for e to become an element of this queue,
                // and for newNode to become "live".
                if (p != t) // hop two nodes at a time
                    casTail(t, newNode);  // Failure is OK.
                return true;
            }
            // Lost CAS race to another thread; re-read next
        }
        else if (p == q)
            // We have fallen off list.  If tail is unchanged, it
            // will also be off-list, in which case we need to
            // jump to head, from which all live nodes are always
            // reachable.  Else the new tail is a better bet.
            p = (t != (t = tail)) ? t : head;
        else
            // Check for tail updates after two hops.
            p = (p != t && t != (t = tail)) ? t : q;
    }
}
```

Comment: Uh, you deal into... Unsafe... Territory. However, my guess here is that a cmpxchg is involved at the CPU level (CoMPare and eXCHanGe). Not sure, though.

Comment: `cas` means “compare and set” and it does what the name suggests, it will compare the old value with the specified first argument (here `null`) and set to the specified second argument (here `newNode`) if the comparison was successful. The special thing is that it is performed *atomically*. There is a [public API providing the same functionality to applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater.html#compareAndSet(T,%20V,%20V))

Comment: In many cases, compareAndSet invokes the `native` api. @fge, your guess is right.

Answer (score 0):

It may operate similar to below pseudo-code, but written in so called native-code (C/C++), which is normally far faster than Java:

```
boolean compareAndSwapObject(Object obj, long fieldId, Object expectedValue, Object newValue) {
    synchronized (globalExchangeLock) {
        if (obj.fieldArray.get(fieldId) == expectedValue) {
            obj.fieldArray.set(fieldId, newValue);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private static final Object globalExchangeLock = new Object();
```

However, passing `fieldId` is little complicated, and maybe should be cached, like below Java code (not pseudo-code this time):

```java
public class MyClass {
    int myField;

    // ...

    private static final sun.misc.Unsafe U = UnsafeAcc.unsafe;
    private static final long MY_FIELD_ID;

    static {
        try {
            MY_FIELD_ID = U.objectFieldOffset(
                MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("myField")
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Which for my Android project uses:

```
/*
 * Written by Stefan Zobel and released to the
 * public domain, as explained at
 * http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/
 */
package java8.util.concurrent;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import sun.misc.Unsafe;

final class UnsafeAcc {

    static final Unsafe unsafe;

    static {
        try {
            Field field = null;
            try {
                field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            } catch (NoSuchFieldException ignored) {
                // For older Androids.
                field = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("THE_ONE");
            }
            field.setAccessible(true);
            unsafe = (Unsafe) field.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Error(e);
        }
    }

    private UnsafeAcc() {
    }
}
```